# What is Purusha Tattva, Prakriti Tattva & Stri Tattva?

Tags: purusha

I wanted to know following terms from scriptures -

- Purusha Tattva
- Prakriti Tattva
- Stri Tattva

And are Stri & Prakriti Tattva **exactly** same?

Comment: Well it is a very good and difficult question, but i know prakriti tatv have something related to chitt and pran

Comment: I will have to ask it from some swami ji, probably there is one swami ji on this S.E. site, he can answer this

Comment: Okay, I will answer but won't be able to answer whether there is Stri Tattva or not.

Comment: from what scripture exactly? If you can give the scripture and verse numbers it is better. Sometimes the words can have different connotations and meanings when used in different scriptures.....

Comment: Sorry sir, there is no Stri Tattva. Nothing like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am adding the definitions of the `Prakiti` and `Purusha` as given by Lord Shiva in the Agamas. BTW, there is nothing called Stri tattva.

The Agama asks the question:

> Atha ka Prakitih?
>
> ....
>
> What is Prakiti?

And answers it by saying:

> GuntrayasAmyavasthaA prakiti.
>
> .....
>
> The state where the Gunatraya (the three Gunas; Sattva etc) assume a
>   balanced state of equilibrium is called the Prakriti.

A more elaborate definition is given by LOrd Shiva in the Shakti Yamala Tantram:

> Sattvam rajastam iti gunatrayamudAhritam | SAmyAvasthi
>   metoshAmavyaktam prakritim viduh || Saiva mula prakritih swAt
>   pradhAnam purshohapi cha |
>
> .......
>
> Satva, Rajo and Tamo; these are spoken of as the three gunas. **The
>   balanced state of equilibrium (sAmyAvyastha) of the three gunas, is
>   known to the wise, as the Avyakta (unmanifest) Praktiti**. And, **that is**
>   the Mula Prakti, the PradhAna and **the PurushA as well**.
>
> **Shakti Yamala**

Now, we need to clarify a bit more regarding  this "Gunatraya sAmyAvavasthA".

> Due to the Jiva's Bhogadustata (the imbalanced state of being
>   afflicted with desires) the three Gunas attain a discriminated and
>   unstable state (nunyadhikya and vaishamya) where is one is dominant
>   over the other and etc. It is from this unstable and differentiated
>   state of the Gunatraya, the manifested universe emerges. After the
>   desire for Bhoga has ended (BhogA avasana), the manifested universe
>   (Jagat) again dissolves back to its Mula Upadana (main raw material)
>   i.e Prakiti. In this non-differentiable and balanced state, the
>   Gunatrayarupa Prakiti ( Prakiti in the form of Gunatraya) exists
>   simply as the cause (kAranrupa) of everything. And, this state is known as
>   Guntraya's akAryAvastha (non working or inactive state) or sAmyavastha
>   ( balanced state).

Lord Shiva gives yet another definition in the JyAna BhAsya Tantram as follows:

> Sattvam rajastam iti gunAnAm tritayam priye | YadA sA ParamA
>
> ShaktirgunAdhisthAnamAcharet | Prakititvam bhavet tasyAh Purushah swAt
>   sadAshivah ||
>
> ........
>
> [Lord says to Sri Devi] Hey Priye ! Sattva, Rajah, Tamah- these are
>   the three Gunas ( Gunatraya). At the time when the Parama Sakti
>   establishes herself (or itself) on the three Gunas, it is then she/it
>   attains Prakiti-hood and it is then the [Nirguna] Purusha (or Shiva)
>    attains SadAshiva-hood.

If one is looking from the perspective of the 36 tattvas then, the following commentary given on **Prapancha sAra Tantram** by PadmAcharya will suffice. All tattvas are different manifestations of the same Parama Shakti which is also known as the Mula Prakriti or the Nirguna Purusha.

> Ekaiva shaktih antarmukhatayA vikashanti vidyAditattvarupini
>   vahirmukhatayA samkuchanti mAyAditattvarupini
>
> ...
>
> The same vimarsha Shakti's inwardly manifestations are the Iswara,
>   VidyA SadAshiva etc tattvas and outwardly contractions are the MAya
>   etc tattvas.

Whenever Shiva is mentioned as the supreme know that its Shakti vishishta Shiva (Shiva with Shakti) and also when Shakti is mentioned likewise know that its Shiva vishishta Shakti. And, the same applies to Purusha-Prakiti too.

Answer (score 3):

To understand *Purusha* & *Prakriti*, Let's first understand the **36**Tattvas which takes part in course of Manifestation.

1. The *tattvas of the Universal experience*. These are Shiva, Sakti, Sadashiva, Isvara & Sadvidya tattvas.
2. The *tattvas of limited individual experience*. These are Maya & it's 5 *Kankukas*.
3. The *tattvas of limited individual*. These are **Purusha** & **Prakriti**.
4. The *tattvas of mental operations*. These are Buddhi, Ahamkar & Manas.
5. The *tattvas of sensible experience*. These are 5 jnanendriyas, 5 karmendriyas & 5 tanmatras.
6. The *tattvas of Materiality*. These are 5 known elements.

Now let's focus on *tattvas of limited individual* -

- **Purusha**-

> Siva  through  Mayasakti  which  limits  His  universal  knowledge and  power  becomes  Purusa  or  the  individual  subject.  Purusa in  this  context  means  every  sentient  being. Purusa  is  also  known  as  anu  in  this  system.  The  word  anu is  used  in  the  sense  of  limitation  of  the  divine  perfection.

- **Prakriti**-

> While  Purusa  is  the  subjective  manifestation  of  Siva,  Prakrti is  the  objective  manifestation. There  is  a  difference  between  the  Sankhya  conception  of Prakrti  and  that  of  Trika.  Sankhya  believes  that  Prakrti  is one  and  universal  for  all  the  Purusas.  Trika  believes  that  each Purusa  has  a  different  Prakrti.  Prakrti  is  the  matrix  of  all Objectivity. Prakrti  has  three  gunas  or  genetic  constituents,  viz.,  sattva, rajas  and  tamas.  In  her  unmanifested  state  Prakrti  holds  these gunas  in  perfect  equipoise.  In  the  order  of  being,  sattva  is characterized  by  brightness  and  lightness,  in  the  psychological order,  it  is  characterized  by  transparency,  joy  and  peace;  in  the ethical  order,  it  is  the  principle  of  goodness.  In  the  order  of being,  tamas  is  the  principle  of  darkness,  inertness;  in  the  psychological  order,  it  is  characterized  by  dullness,  delusion  and dejection,  and  in  the  ethical  order,  it  is  the  principle  of  degradation,  debasement.  In  the  order  of  being,  rajas  is  characterized  by activity;  in  the  psychological  order,  it  is  characterized  by  craving and  passion;  in  the  ethical  order,  it  is  the  principle  of ambition  and  avarice. According  to  Pratyabhijna,  Prakrti  is  the  Santa  Sakti  of  Siva, and  the  gunas  sattva,  rajas  and  tamas  are  only  the  polarization  of His  saktis  of  jnana,  iccha  and  kriya  respectively.  Thus  in  the Pratyabhijna  system,  there  is  perfect  non-dualism,  not  dualism of  Prakrti  and  Purusa,  as  in  Sankhya. Purusa  is  the  experient  (bhokta)  and  Prakrti  is  the  experienced (bhogya).

**There is nothing like Stri Tattva.** There are only these 36 Tattvas, no less no more.

Ref- **Shiv Sutras by Jaidev Singh**