# does any scripture say worship must be in Sanskrit?

Tags: worship, sanskrit

The most prominent non-Sanskrit scripture is the Tamil Divya prabandham of Southern Vaishnavites.  Non-brahmin Tamils don't have a great love of Sanskrit and one can increasingly see them conduct Puja and even yagnas in Tamil.  I have seen Hindu worship conducted in English also.

Have scriptures said anything about this?

Comment: Scriptures are those which are in Sanskrit and not any other languages..

Comment: "Scriptures are those which are in Sanskrit and not any other languages" - thats only opinion and an extreme one at that.  So ram charit manas is not scripture?  per wiki - "In many temples — Srirangam, for example — the chanting of the Divya Prabhandham forms a major part of the daily service."  you are entitled to your opinion, but I am looking for scripture citations @rickross

Comment: No that is not an extreme stand.. Vedas, Tantras, Puranas, Smritis etc are the scriptures and they are all in Sanskrit.. Few exceptions here and there can not change the general rule.

Comment: S.K check my another answer. All Sanskrit words (sounds to be precise) have one to one correspondence with Tattvas.

Comment: Check this-   https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19827/sanskrit-and-sounds-of-lord-shiva/19837#19837

Comment: sorry @rajas - all this sounds fanciful.  What is verifiable is that the gravitas of Sanskrit has steadily declined from Rig Veda to later works like itihasas and puranas.  people are now voting with their feet by shifting to their native languages for prayer because sanskrit does nothing for them.

Comment: SK I'm just claiming Sanskrit have one to one correspondence with the Tattvas, nothing else. And I believe love & consciousness is the language with which we talk to the Shiva, not Sanskrit. Sanskrit does have huge  significance, but it is not the mandatory language to convey our prayer or messages to the Shiva.

Comment: @Rickross, Tamil Divya Prabandhams are regarded as scripture because they are Tamil Vedas. Stanza by Stanza it's a divine translation of Rig/Yajur/Sama/Atharva vedas.

Comment: Think of Sanskrit as sounds rather than language. Then it would be like asking whether a flute music can be played by a violin. Yagna mantras must be in Sanskrit. Divya Prabandhas are not mantras in strict sense, so they can be used when worshiping Lord cos devotion can be offered in any language.

Comment: @ram If word to word translations of a scripture is another scripture then that's a problem.. as many languages as many scriptures.. we need to keep the scriptures and their translations separate.. also i don't think there can be Bengali Veda, Gujarati Veda and so on :D.. also pls don't get hurt by my comment.

Comment: @Rickross, not hurt at all. Tamil is regarded as ancient language.. there is a saying 'Aagastyam is anaadi' - Agastya rishi propounded Tamil rules of grammar, so Tamil is called Aagastyam.. and it is 'beginning less'. If Bengali/Gujarati etc. are also ancient, sure. Btw, i only used the word 'translation' so regular folks can understand. It is called Tamil Veda because there is a mapping between it and Sanskrit veda for e.g. Purusha Sooktham has an equivalent chapter etc. No other language has this. It is not sung by regular humans, but Azhwars (incarnations of divine beings/weapons of Vishnu)

Answer (score 6):

Sanskrit alphabets are considered as deities and are present in the chakras. Hence Sanskrit is recommended for use in worship and mantras. If you look at the iconography of Mother Kali you will see that she is garlanded by 50 human skulls that denote the Sanskrit alphabets or deities. However, use of Sanskrit is not mandatory. Unfortunately the Swami does not quote any scripture for his assertion.

> Among the Vedic sacred formulas, the Gayatri has been prescribed for
>   repetition from ancient times. The Vedic people had great faith in the
>   efficacy of mantras. The Mimamsakas considered mantras to be the
>   embodiments of deities. In fact, they accepted no deities other than
>   the mantras at all. To them Brahman is nothing but sound (shabda), and
>   sound produces form. Thus, the name embodied in the mantra is more
>   real than the form of the deity. .... Forms are made up of nothing but
>   fine vibrations, and vibrations are produced by sound only, so these
>   ancient conceptions are tenable. From another point of view, a mantra
>   gains spiritual potency through many years of being associated with
>   holy men who have repeated it and attained realization through it. The
>   concept of the mantra is based on the psychological fact that much of
>   our thinking depends on auditory symbols. Repetition of the mantra
>   creates a chain of thought which induces the mind with the thought of
>   God, and this is the aim of all spiritual practices. 
>   ................. Every Vedic mantra has a rishi who first intuited
>   it, a particular metre in which it is composed, and a deity to whom it
>   is addressed. In Tantric mantras the most important element is the
>   vija, a sacred syllable considered to be charged with spiritual
>   potency, as also Shakti or power and a kilaka, a pillar (inner
>   syllables on which the mantra rests.) **All the letters of the
>   alphabets are considered as different matrikas, minor deities around
>   the main deity.** The mantra is charged with a special potency, so
>   much so that the Tantrikas believe that when offerings are made to the
>   deity with the appropriate mantras, the deity accepts them
>   immediately. ......... The Chandogya Upanishad I.1.10 says about the
>   efficacy of the repetition of Om: Both perform spiritual practices -
>   he who knows and he who does not know. But knowledge and ignorance are
>   different in their effects. Whatever is performed with knowledge,
>   faith and meditation, becomes spiritually effective.

Meditation and other spiritual disciplines by Swami Swahananda

There is an extensive discussion of Vaidika sabda in "The Garland of letters' by Sir John Woodroffe.

> In the Yoga Bhasya that is Vyasa's commentary on the Patanjala-Darsana
>   (3.17) it is said: *Tatra vagvarnesvarthavatiti*. According to this,
>   each letter is intrinsically Sarvabhidhana-sakti-prachita, that is
>   possesing the power (Sakti) to denote and connote all objects
>   (Artha). For as the Visvasara-Tantra says:'What is not here is nowhere'.
>   **A letter (Varna) is the whole cosmos in miniature.** One Varna differs
>   from another in the relative latency of the universe of Artha involved
>   in it, the universe being the same in both. They come to denote
>   special Arthas by virtue of the order (Krama) of their collocation. 
>   ...... But the ultimate philosophical question is, "who, if any
>   one, first said that this sound meant that thing?" The Indian answer
>   is that the relation of the word and the object denoted are eternal
>   and not a conventional thing, that  there is a system of Natural
>   names, whatever in fact that may be.'

The Garland of Letters chapter IX by Sir John Woodroffe

What the above quote means is that the Sanskrit words of a mantra for deity worship are not mere human invention. The implication of using a non-Sanskrit language is that the word that is eternally linked with a certain object is not being used. If that is not a concern then one can indeed use any language.

Let me use a concrete example. Take the word AUM=OM. OM stands for Brahman whether Saguna or Nirguna. Is OM a mere human convention? Did some people choose to use OM as the symbol of Brahman? The answer is no. OM is the eternal sound symbol of Brahman. Can we replace OM by say GY? Yes, we can indeed replace OM by GY from the intellectual point of view. All of us would associate GY with Brahman by convention. However, is GY a mantra? The answer is no according to mantra sastra. GY is a mere human convention and will never be a mantra.

Let me sum up the situation as I understand it. If one prays to God then one can use any language. Sanskrit is not needed. If one wants to meditate then any language can be used. One can chant in any language. Sanskrit is not required. Texts which are recognised by many as scripture can be in any language. Sanskrit is not necessary. Sanskrit is necessary if one wants to use any mantra. Just think of Tibetan Buddhists. They do not accept the concept of Brahman. Yet they use OM in the mantra 'Om Mani padme hum. The reason is that the Sanskrit matrikas are present in every human chakras and Sanskrit mantras take advantage of this fact.

Comment: Yes, letter <=> deities.  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19837/8696

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes, atleast as per [Kāraṇāgama](https://archive.org/details/karan-agama-by-r.-m.-prabhulinga-shastri-shaiva-bharati-varanasi/page/n1/mode/2up) (कारणागम), one of the 28 Śaivāgamas, Sanskrit is the only way to worship.

> क्रियापादः
> ॥ पञ्चमः पटलः ॥
>
> आख्याति पूजावेलायां वैदिकं यदूचक्षणः ।
> तन्मयैवोदितमिति निर्वहत् स्वप्रयत्नतः ।।१६।।
>
> > **Sanskrit is the language of Shiva, hence, only the person, who could know and speak in Sanskrit or Vedik language, ought to master the pooja.** (16)
>
> अवैदिकस्याख्यातॄणां निकटे नोपवेशयेत् ।
>  प्रत्याख्यानं न कुर्वीत पिदध्याच्छ्रवणदूयम् ।
> नेक्षेत पूजावेलायां नरं देवि बहिष्कृतम् ।।१७।।
>
> > **The person, who speaks in non-Sanskrit, isn't allowed to sit near practitioner.** The practitioner ought not to answer him and close ears to his words. Ah Devi! Practitioner ought not to see towards the person who is boycotted from the pooja. (17)
>
> [Fifth Chapter](https://archive.org/details/karan-agama-by-r.-m.-prabhulinga-shastri-shaiva-bharati-varanasi/page/n87/mode/2up), Kriyāpādah, Kāraṇāgama
> English Translation by R. M. Prabhulinga Shastri