# Is Krittivasi Ramayana authentic?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, rama, vaishnavism

1.Is Krittivasi Ramayana an authentic scripture or is it just a literacy work?
Should we consider statements from that Ramayana as authentic ?

2.If it is authentic,then has any acharya from any sampradaya (especially from vaishnavism) ever quoted anything from it?

3.What is it's status now in our dharmic culture and how Famous is it in bengal regions?

Please try to answer all the parts separately.

Comment: Krittivasi Ramayana is a completely literary work similar to the Jagamohan Ramayana of Odisha & Saptakanda Ramayana of Madhava Kandali from Assam . It isn't a word-to-word translation of the Valmiki Ramayana.

Comment: The translator Krittivasa Ojha inserted many anecdotes into the main story which might have scriptural reference (most famously Shri Ramachandra worshipping Bhagavati Durga in autumn for defeating Ravana is also mentioned in the Devi Bhagavata Purana, Kalika Purana & Brihaddharma Purana) or not (like Shri Ramachandra assuming the form of Shri Krishna on the request of Garuda after he freed him from the Nagapasha).

Comment: @AnubrataBit What about the instances like Ravana giving knowledge to Lord Lakshmana and Hanuman ji tearing his chest ? Are they present in any other scripture apart from Krittivasi Ramayana and should we consider those statements true ??

Comment: Since the translators didn't compose their works with the intention of creating a new canonical text, they had the liberty to add material from other sources or by will (for example Krittivasa makes Sita chastise Rama when she is asked to prove her chastity in Uttarakanda by making Sita say that she never had to suffer so much in his any other avatara or Ravana advising Lakshmana against procrastinating any work). The main motive of translating the epics was to make religious knowledge accesible to the common masses.

Comment: @AnubrataBit okkk.. I Understood :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't comment on the authenticity of any text within Hinduism or outside, because in the religious sphere it is the belief and faith of a particular follower, and the whole community at large, in the religion (and its scriptures) that determine the "authenticity".

However, we do have a very clear scriptural injunction in the āgamas, as regards what might constitute an "acceptable text of Hinduism".

As I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50532/17833), the Kāraṇāgama (कारणागम) (one of the 28 Śaivāgamas), clearly states that worship in Hinduism must be in the Vedik language - i.e., Sanskrit.

> क्रियापादः ॥ पञ्चमः पटलः ॥
>
> आख्याति पूजावेलायां वैदिकं यदूचक्षणः । 
> तन्मयैवोदितमिति निर्वहत्
> स्वप्रयत्नतः ।।१६।।
>
> > 16. **Sanskrit is the language of Shiva, hence, only the person, who could
> >     know and speak in Sanskrit or Vedik language, ought to master the
> >     pooja.**

In fact, even worshipping in the Prākṛta (प्राकृत) language is forbidden, which is kind of "unrefined-Sanksrit", let alone any other language and their respective texts.

> सर्वमप्राकृतैर्मन्त्रैः कृत्वा मह्यं समर्पयेत् । 
> शुद्धभावः समभ्यर्च्य यथोक्तफलभाग भवेत् ।। २७ ।।
>
> > [27.](https://archive.org/details/karan-agama-by-r.-m.-prabhulinga-shastri-shaiva-bharati-varanasi/page/n89/mode/2up) **All deeds ought to be offered to Shiva with hymns in the Sanskrit language, not in Prakrit.** The Pooja performed sincerely would give the result acceptable by the spiritual science.
>
> English Translation by R. M. Prabhulinga Shastri

---

So any text not following the above guideline might be excluded from the authentic scriptures.

There **might** still be some exceptions here and there. Like the Rāmacaritamānasa in Awadhi language, the Nālāyira Divya Prabandham in Tamil, but even these texts don't command a pan-Hinduism status of scriptures, and more like Regional or sectarain status, perhaps.

Overall, exceptions don't define the general rule, that is well known.

Comment: Okk I understood..Could you please answer the 3rd part of question ? That is missing in answer

Comment: @ShriRambhakt Your question's part (3) is opinion-based, I think. And I don't think that Krittivasi commands an authority pan-Hinduism, maybe in Bengal, it is very popular because obviously, it's in Bengali, but can't say the same for whole Hinduism though!

Comment: Yes I got it now. Different people might have different opinions regarding Krittivasi Ramayana .