# How to do Sandyavandanam in English

Tags: vedas, sandhyavandanam

I would like to understand and express the sandhyavandanam in English. Is there a process/resource that can do the same ritual in English?

Comment: Not possible to do it in English. I mean you can but it won't serve the purpose. Unless you meant transliteration and not translation

Comment: Tell these mantra's in a language you know and the results will follow. again, one need to know what he or she is saying.

Comment: @junkone you may read translation of the hymn and understand it. But reciting before Ishwar do it in Sanskrit. If you're not familiar with Devanagari or other Indian scripts then use English transliteration, which is what used by foreigners while reading Sanskrit. Hope that helps

Comment: @junkone Welcome to HSE! Please be nice to each-other. About your question, Are you looking for English transliteration of Sanskrit verses?

Comment: i am looking for transulaton so i can do the rituals in english instead of sanskrit

Comment: @junkone As far as I know there is no such word as "transulaton". Could you tell me the meaning of the word?

Comment: ok. its translation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i did look at the isckon site and here is something that seems to be a transulation.
https://iskcondesiretree.com/profiles/blogs/tri-vedi-sandhya-vandanam-1

This one is actually better and more understandable. i can do the english words along to get the effect.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9b31khruk4
Another good resource that i am using to mentally transulate is I am following this and doing it in english and i feel like i can connect with the process. http://hinduonline.co/DigitalLibrary/SmallBooks/UpakarmaVidhanaSanEng.pdf

Comment: ISKCON is not a scripture and their opinions cannot be taken as authoritative on something so essential as sandhyavandanam. In addition, the website you linked is not even from ISKCON: it is merely a blog written by someone who claims to be affiliated with it.

Comment: atleast, its something better than what i heard so far. so if there is truly a better resource, share it.

Comment: Is the following PDF something you are looking for? -- https://andhra-telugu.com/files/Bhakti/surya_Navagraha/Sandhya%20Vandanam%20Procedure.pdf @junkone

Comment: its similar to the one i attached. But the one i found from hinduonline.co and attached had the actual meaning. i just tell the meaning out loud and i can notice the difference in the experience of the process.

Comment: @junkone oh so you chant only the meanings and not the mantras?

Comment: I chant only what i can communicate with God through my understanding.

Comment: @junkone that's interesting .. one of my Gurus have actually said to us (the disciples) that if we have trouble chanting the mantras or slokas in Sanskrit then we can chant their Bengali meaning (we are Bengali that's why). He also has provided us with books that contain the Bengali meanings. But I don't think this is widely followed and quite possibly it does not have explicit scriptural sanction

Comment: Hinduism is decentralized and so the scriptural sanctions dont have any value. The life cycle of the process is do the actions that gives you the results you seek.

All of this is principles and habits. sometimes we use metaphor's to communicate.

In Bhagavad-Gita Lord Krishna said that everything happens for a cause or good reason. Whatever happens in life happen for good and there is always a cause or reason behind that. 
How can we adapt the prayers to a language we understand?

Comment: @junkone Your comments are not notifying me as you are not using atmyusername in them. We can adapt by translating it. For example "Om Suryaya namah" can be made into an English prayer "Om salutations to Surya (sun god)". Now whether it will have the same efficacy as the original mantra/prayer or not is something that no one knows.

Comment: @rickross this is what i have started and i can see the difference. the key differentiator is that i can visualize and verbalize at the same time. I do have skills from other practises of mindfulness to detect and notice  see, hear , feel experiences. 
I am building it on notion and so feel free to contribute. 
When i feel that chant when i am doing the chanting and understanding it, i invoke the experience within me. 
https://ballistic-casquette-1d7.notion.site/Quick-Note-2dedc8cda3d14749b8a32a40dcbda785

Comment: That's cool if it's working for you .. I have seen from experience too that spiritually inclined persons always find a way ... no obstacle is an obstacle for them @junkone (and this time your comment did notify me)

Answer (score 2):

As per Orthodox or traditional viewpoints from scriptures, such kind of worship is forbidden, for Sanskrit is the only language to be used for worshipping.

As I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50532/17833)

> क्रियापादः 
> ॥ पञ्चमः पटलः ॥
>
> आख्याति पूजावेलायां वैदिकं यदूचक्षणः ।
>  तन्मयैवोदितमिति निर्वहत्
> स्वप्रयत्नतः ।।१६।।
>
> > 16. **Sanskrit is the language of Shiva, hence, only the person, who could
> >     know and speak in Sanskrit or Vedik language, ought to master the
> >     pooja.**
>
> [Chapter 5](https://archive.org/details/karan-agama-by-r.-m.-prabhulinga-shastri-shaiva-bharati-varanasi/page/n87/mode/2up), Kriyāpādah, Kāraṇāgama
>
> English Translation by R. M. Prabhulinga Shastri

---

#### One cannot perform 'sandhya-vandanam' in any other language besides Sanskrit.

So there cannot be any "traditional-resource" on the English language-based 'sandhya-vandanam'.

Comment: Bhakti has no language, everyone is free to convey in their own language in Bhakti. However, rituals are taken from scriptures, specifically, the Vedic-Rituals for dvijas must be performed in Sanskrit. Just like Programming cannot be in Sanskrit. Hope that helps you!:)

Comment: @junkone Please be nice to fellow users on this platform. We all are here to help each other by sharing authentic information. :-)

Comment: I had a simple question and all i get is rude answers that its not possible. pl lecture the people who are giving me such rude answers

Comment: I am following this and doing it in english and i feel like i can connect with the process. http://hinduonline.co/DigitalLibrary/SmallBooks/UpakarmaVidhanaSanEng.pdf